# Process all files with a given ending in a directory

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to find and **process all files with a given ending** (.txt in the example below) in a directory. My current example finds all files containing .txt anywhere in the file name (e.g. also files with the ending .txt*, e.g. .txt.xls).

```
DATADIR=$1

for DATA in `ls $DATADIR`; do
  DATABASENAME=$(basename $DATA)
  echo "Basename of file $DATABASENAME"

  if [[ ${DATABASENAME} =~ .*txt ]];
  then
    DATAPATH="$DATADIR$DATABASENAME"

    echo "File path $DATAPATH"
  fi 
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, that is the for loop you want:

```
for file in *.txt ; do
```

Comment: To add the idea of @Hans to the example, replace the if with if [[ ${DATABASENAME} == *.txt ]]. ${DATABASENAME} =~ .*\.txt$ is also correct (the $ specifies the end of the word).